# Getting the width and height of an image attachment

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is it possible to get the width and height of an image in an Attachment?

I'm looking for a way to make it show properly based on the image.

```
<apex:image value="https://c.ap1.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!a.Id}" width="XXX" height="XXX"/>
```

Comment: This seems like a great place where VF should be able to fill them in automatically... If you post on the IdeaExchange and update here with the link, I'll vote for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried following code and its alerting the width and height correctly. One approach would be to load images like this and add them to the dom as required

```
<apex:page>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      // you can append this img tag in desired DOM location now with height/width as required.
      alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
    }
    img.src = 'https://c.ap1.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/06890000000MkxY';

  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Another approach might be to do like this

```
<apex:page>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<apex:image id="testImg" value="/s.gif" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('img[id$=testImg]')             
            .attr('src', 'https://c.ap1.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/06890000000MkxY')
            .load(function(){        
            // do what you want with height width here
                alert($(this).height() + ' X ' + $(this).width());

            });
    });
  </script>
</apex:page>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can this be done solely from the controller side without using javascript?