# Get image size (height & width) and reject images bigger than 200X100 px

Tags: visualforce, javascript, images, richtextarea

On a VF page, I added a Rich Text Area field called Logo__c where users can upload their company's logo. One of the requirements is to reject images that are bigger than 200X100 px.

I saw [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1128/38518) answer which uses Javascript to check for the size of the image (although it refers to an attachment), What I want is to modify the code below and change the image's source to a Salesforce field (Logo__c) instead of the URL. How can this be achieved?

```
<apex:page>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <apex:image id="testImg" value="/s.gif" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('img[id$=testImg]')
                .attr('src', 'https://c.ap1.content.force.com/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/download/06890000000MkxY')
                .load(function() {
                    // do what you want with height width here

                    alert($(this).height() + ' X ' + $(this).width());
                    if ($(this).height() > 200 || $(this).width() > 100) {
                        apply logic....
                    }

                });
        });

    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? `@(this).height()` should be `$(this).height()`

Comment: I'm not sure how to retrieve the image's dimensions from Logo__c and 'reject' the image and prompt the user to upload a different one.

Comment: I fixed the typo

Comment: You should check the height and width in Javascript before uploading to the Rich Text Area. Check this Stackoverflow link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8903854/check-image-width-and-height-before-upload-with-javascript

Comment: @SarojBera I tried it but it does not recognize the richtextfield as an input field. I posted part of the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/ghjz9kf7/

Comment: Rich Text Area can't take a file as input. How the user will upload an image in Rich Text Field. Are you expecting the user to copy and paste the image? Rather you should provide file input dialog to upload the image then show it in Rich Text area.

Comment: No need to copy and paste, there is a dedicated button for it: https://s7.postimg.org/c8f1rkiez/img.png